# Button inside Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I need Button at bottom of Navigation Drawer i have added linearlayout also inside drawer layout but m getting class cast exception for drawer layout from that linear layout, my code is

```
            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_gravity="right"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/content_frame"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="240dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                                     <Button
                                          android:id="@+id/btn_Apply"
                                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/right_drawer_list"
                            android:layout_width="400dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                            android:divider="@android:colortransparent"
                            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                            android:background="#111"/>
```

Comment: Show your code which causes the ClassCastException.

Comment: I would argue that a `Button`, let alone an `EditText`, would violate Google's design guidelines for a navigation drawer: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: @HpTerm: The navigation drawer pattern is most certainly supported, and `DrawerLayout` is not marked as deprecated. If you have evidence to the contrary, please post it!

Comment: @HpTerm: Use `DrawerLayout`, as is being used in the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you very much for pointing me to that very important point ! I remove all my comments here as they are useless.

Comment: hey guys the problem was solved m casting that linear layout with by default list view thats why the exception was thrown butt thankss for your comments ,it helps me a lot...